# How to do a database relation to entities that share same fields

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I have two entities, one parent and other child. I have statistics of a parent (count, views, comments), and also I have statistics of parent's child (count, views, comments). Parents and children share the same fields, but they have a relation one to many (one parent has many children).

I'm confused about how to model this situation.

I'm not sure wheather will be more efficient create two tables and use foreign keys (tables will almost have the same fields, except that child's table will have a parentId).

The other situation could be put all data (parent and child) in the same table and try to do an itself relationship.

Which of this options would be more efficient?

I'm open to consider others suggestions.

Note that this tables will storage millions of records, that will be select later.

Comment: Please show some design(s). (Your descriptions are too vague anyway.) Please read & act on [mcve]. "Efficient" means nothing--please google questions about it & synonyms, including my comments about "best".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your explanation,

> tables will almost have the same fields, except that child's table
>   will have a parentId

it's better to use **Unary Relationship** and put `parent` and `child` in **one Table** and use `null` `parentId` for parents.

**But** sometimes we can extract some attributes to another table. 
If actions on some fields are so much (e.g. so many updates on some fields), it's better to extract them in other table.

In this case (if you have many actions on these fields), you can put `count`, `views`, `comments` in other table and make a one-to-one relationship between main table.